# "infinite scroll" section for my e-commerce website interfering with my CSS grid layout

Tags: css

So I want an "infinite scrolling" functionality on my website to load more pages and extend the section while remaining on the same page, but the way I have it set up is super sketchy because the grid doesn't expand with the section as new divs are created. So essentially what is happening is, visually the sections expand, but when adding new sections they display in the middle of the other sections. I've seen grid-auto-rows property but I'm not sure how that would work if I need a full template with different layouts depending on what part of the page it is. Is there a way to use grid and allow the grid template to expand, or do I just have to change the entire template with javascript to expand it manually everytime more content is added?

```
.main-container{
    grid-column: 1 / 11;
    grid-row: 2 / 7;

    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(10, 1fr) / repeat(12, 1fr);
}

/* Mobile Section Wrappers */

.filters-wrapper{
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    height: 37px;
}

.recommended-wrapper{
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    text-align: center;
}

.hot-products-wrapper{
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Mobile Sections */

.filters{
    text-align: center;
}

.recommended{
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.hot-products{
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

/* Mobile Section Contents */

#sort-by{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}

.filters label{
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}

.listing{
    background: #d2def7;
    height: 198px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
}

.listing img{
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    object-fit: cover;
}

.listing h5{
    margin-top: 4px;
}

/* Mobile Misc */

.recommended-wrapper h4, .hot-products-wrapper h4{
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Home | Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" />
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/97dd8e84b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Rubik Font-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Oswald Font-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <img alt="Website Logo" src="images/web-site-logo.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <form method="POST" action="search.php">
                        <button type="submit" id="search-submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
                        <input type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Search BitList...">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <a class="cart-btn" href="cart.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
                    <a id="menu-btn" class="menu-btn" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a>
                    <a class="logout-btn" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="filters-wrapper">
                    <div class="filters">
                        <label for="sort-by">sort by:</label>
                        <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
                            <option>Most relevant</option>
                            <option>Newest</option>
                            <option>Oldest</option>
                            <option>Price - Low to high</option>
                            <option>Price - High to low</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="recommended-wrapper">
                    <h4>RECOMMENDED FOR YOU</h4>
                    <div class="recommended">
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/bitcoin.png">
                                <h5>Bitcoin Souvenir Physical Alloy Coin</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/camera.jpg">
                                <h5>Canon SuperShot DSLR Professional Camera</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/desktop.jpg">
                                <h5>Desktop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/iphone.jpg">
                                <h5>Brand new iPhone 12 Pro Max</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/headset.jpg">
                                <h5>Headset w/ microphone</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/jeans.jpg">
                                <h5>Women's denim jeans size 32/34</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/mouse.jpg">
                                <h5>RAZER DeathAdder Gaming Mouse</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/shirt.png">
                                <h5>Bitcoin tee-shirt</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/yeti.jpg">
                                <h5>Yeti 30oz Tumbler Insulated Cup</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/shoes.png">
                                <h5>Adidas FreeRun 8 Men's Running Shoes</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="recommended-more-btn">
                        <a href="#">show more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hot-products-wrapper">
                    <h4>HOT PRODUCTS</h4>
                    <div class="hot-products">
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Laptop" src="uploads/laptop.jpg">
                                <h5>Laptop RTX 2080ti, Ryzen 2700x CPU, 16GB DDR4 3200MHz</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="recommended-more-btn">
                        <a href="#">show more</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) and [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware, I just saw other people doing it and figured there might be a reason but was too lazy to actually look it up